# Problem with continue instruction after rand() function

Tags: c, random, conditional-statements, continue

I just wanted to solve an exercise that asks me to write a routine to generate a set of even random numbers between 2 to 10.

The problem is when printing, because I want the last number not to be followed by a comma.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int i, a, b, c;

    i = a = b = c = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        a = rand() % 8 + 2;

        if ((i <= 10) && (a % 2) != 0)
        {   
            continue;
        }
        printf((i < 10) ? "%d, " : "%d\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And these are two execution examples:

```
4, 4, 2, 8,
2, 8, 6, 4, 2
```

In one the comma does not appear at the end but in another it does. When debugging I see that the error happens when the last number is odd, because the continue statement causes it to go to the next iteration.

Comment: You might find it easier to print the comma before all of the numbers except the first. You might also use a function to generate only even numbers and then just call it however many times you need to. It isn't clear how many numbers you actually need and the extra conditionals and the continue inside the loop are kinda just noise. `i` will never be anything other than `<= 10` since that is your for loop condition and you could just print the `\n` outside the loop at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Retired Ninja has said, there are many unnecessary conditionals that can be avoided. I have revised your code so that `a` will always generate an even number between `2` and `10`, thereby removing the need for the logic you implemented. This is what I have assigned this new `a` value as:

```
a = ((rand() % 4) * 2 + 2);
```

This generates a random value between `[0,4]`, multiplies it by 2, and adds 2, for an integer between 2 and 10, noninclusive. Since your new `a` is always even, I removed your logic to check whether the number is even.

**Revised code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int i, a, b, c;

    i = a = b = c = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        a = ((rand() % 4) * 2 + 2);
        printf((i < 10) ? "%d, " : "%d\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this code will always produce 9 numbers, as you have not specified how many values to print each time, just that you need to "write a routine to generate a set of even random numbers between 2 to 10". You can always change the amount of numbers printed by changing the value of `i` in the `for` loop. The comma issue, however, is not a problem anymore.

If my solution has helped you, please [mark my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) as the correct answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, both were very helpful and although the problem does not specify how many numbers are necessary, it does seem important to define it.

Comment: Indeed, it is important to specify how many numbers are necessary for a problem like this. Thanks for marking my answer